# Pass custom code to JOptionsPane (X)

Tags: java

I asked a similar question earlier in the week but now the problem is back in my face and I really need to get a solution so hopefully someone can help me.

My question is pretty simple. If I have a JOptionPane can I pass custom directions to the (X) in the top corner? I currently have custom instruction passed if the user presses "Cancel", and "Ok" by default will close the window. I want pressing the (X) to execute System.exit(0).

My program is basically a long chain of JOptionPane's. I am aware creating a custom JFrame and full GUI would have been the better way to go but at the time I didn't expect the project to amount to much so it began with JOptionPane's and that is where I am at currently.

I find it rather annoying that the "X" button is treated the same as "Ok" (Closes the window). I don't think it's possible for me to set custom instruction but if so how do I do it?

Do I need to set a custom if statement for "Ok" to close the window and then say "else" program closes? That way if the user clicks anything other than "ok" or "cancel" the program quits (I am assuming that the "X" would be the only other option).

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myframe.setTitle("");
JOptionPane.show...Dialog(myFrame, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing is in a JFrame. Actually these are individual JOptionPane's that pop up one after the other.

Comment: The first arguement of any JOptionPane call is a parent component. Instead of giving "null", pass "new JFrame()". @jesric1029

Comment: I passed the argument for new JFrame() but then what? Do I need to implement the answer that Reinard gave as well?

Comment: @jesric1029 modified my answer.